# Deploying React/Vite project from GitHub pages and assigning custom domain but it shows error: net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages, vite

Deploying React/Vite project from GitHub pages and assigning custom domain, it lead to blank page and it shows error in console:
GET https://{justplaceholderformyurl}/Portfolio/assets/index-f7682910.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404             GET https://{justplaceholderformyurl}/Portfolio/assets/index-d7e9badf.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
When i am deploying without custom domain just GitHub pages it works fine.
When deploying in GitHub pages with custom domain to static (HTML,CSS) not (React/Vite) it works fine. Therefore custom domain configured correctly.
Thank you for your help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi7K1.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.